# Multiplicative order of 10 modulo p

Tags: modular-arithmetic, multiplicative-order

While the multiplicative order of $10$ modulo $2$ or $5$ does not exist, the multiplicative order of $10$ modulo $p$ for $p\geq 7$ prime is not necessarily $p-1$ ($2$ for $p=11$, $6$ for $p=13$, and not $36$ for $37$).

How do I produce a generalisation to find the multiplicative order of $10$  modulo some arbitrary prime $p$?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I'm trying to find the smallest value k such that $10^k\equiv 1$  in modulo p for generalization of prime, where k is the multiplicative order.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still none the wiser.... "generalization of prime" .... what's that?

Comment: Generalisation of prime just means a possible rule that defines k for all prime numbers as modulo, I am sorry .if I am still

Comment: Unclear, I will try to explain

Comment: The order of $10$ modulo $3$ very much exists: it's $1$.

Comment: Yes, this I made a mistake of, sorry.

Comment: If $\gcd(p,10)=1$, then $10^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. So the number you are looking for must be a divisor of $p-1$. As far as I know, there is no formula for which divisor it is.

Comment: But why does $10^6\equiv \text{ (mod 13)}$ in addition to $10^{12}$?

Comment: Edited so that the question makes sense, and took into account @Arthur's remark.

Comment: Look at the link below for Euler's theorem on repeated decimals. https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi%3Farticle%3D1047%26context%3Dmathfacpub&ved=2ahUKEwjHlp7cv6bcAhUX448KHar4CBwQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw2t6f6GZs6E39P2u6Er2Ed5

Comment: If E.T.Bell is to be trusted Gauss himself tried to figure this out. He couldn't, but the law of quadratic reciprocity came out instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no formula for calculating the order of an element modulo a prime. The only method is (essentially) to start calculating. (There are shortcuts to speed that up in some cases, but nothing that's really fast or easy.)

Marking this answer community wiki.)